# Compare multiple array values and update table status

Tags: php, html, mysql, arrays

If there are three records, I want to compare the values
of 'test1' and 'test 2' and update database to 'open' or 'close', if 'test1' and 'test2' values of three records matches the same. But the below code doesn't work.

**HTML:**

```
    while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql)){
        <input type="text" value="<?php echo $row['test1']; ?>" name="test1[]">
        <input type="text" value="" name="test2[]">
    }
  <input name="Submit" type="submit" value="update">
```

**PHP:**

```
<?php

if (isset($_POST['Submit']))
{
$test1=$_POST['test1'];
$test2=$_POST['test2'];

if($test1==$test2)
{
$sql1="UPDATE table SET status='close' WHERE test1='$test1' AND test2='$test2' ";
$db=mysql_query($sql1);
}
else
{
$sql1="UPDATE table SET status='open' WHERE test1='$test1' AND test2='$test2' ";
$db=mysql_query($sql1);
}
}

?>
```

Comment: Change name of inputs without the []..

Comment: Your question is not at all clear. I can't even begin to wrap my head around what you are trying to do here. You might also remove tags for dbms that you aren't using. sql-server <> mysql

Comment: No. The html comes inside the loop.

Comment: Updated. Please check now

Comment: Then you should google for how to compare 2 arrays with each other.. Since [] in html creates an array on the PHP side..

Comment: And is that code contained in `<form method='post' action = ''>....</form>` ?

Comment: yes. It is inside the form

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to compare array values. try below code,

```
<?php
    $three = array_intersect($test1,$test2);

    if(count($three) > 2)
    {
    $sql1="UPDATE table SET status='close' WHERE test1='$test1' AND test2='$test2' ";
    $db=mysql_query($sql1);
    }
    else
    {
    $sql1="UPDATE table SET status='open' WHERE test1='$test1' AND test2='$test2' ";
    $db=mysql_query($sql1);
    }
?>
```